# ArrayList add not working in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This my code. onooltuud is an `ArrayList`. I get datas Firebase then add the onooltuud arrayList. But arrayList size 0. Caution incoming data from Firebase. Help me.

```
 public class OnooltActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
ArrayList<String> onooltuud = new ArrayList<String>();`

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.onoolt_activity_2);



    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref = database.getReference("db").child("davaa").child(String.valueOf(davaaniiNo) + "-iinDavaa");
    Query query = ref.orderByChild("onooltDugaar");

    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int temp = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            Log.i("count", String.valueOf(temp));
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.i("snapshot", snapshot.getValue().toString());
                Onoolt onoolt = snapshot.getValue(Onoolt.class);
                onoolts.add(onoolt.getOnooltDugaar());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(OnooltActivity2.this, "Датаг уншиж чадсангүй: " + databaseError.getCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });

    Log.i("testSize:", String.valueOf(onoolts.size()));
```

this my code onoolts add not working

Comment: Where are you adding to `onooltuud`?

Comment: You array is called `onooltuud`, instead or `onoolts.add(onoolt.getOnooltDugaar());` put `onooltuud.add(onoolt.getOnooltDugaar());`

Comment: You just log in the error place

Comment: @LieForBananas :: Maybe you should add that solution tip as an Answer!  I don't thing the OP is able to understand your suggest  without a more structured response.

Comment: @Barns you are right, I'll add it as an answer with more details :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says that the `size()` of your `Arraylist` object `onooltuud` is zero (= 0) because you never add anything to it. You declared your `ArrayList` like that:

```
ArrayList<String> onooltuud = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And when you add elements you use a different name:

```
onoolts.add(onoolt.getOnooltDugaar());
```

The names do not correspond: **onooltuud** vs **onoolts**.

Delete this line:

```
onoolts.add(onoolt.getOnooltDugaar());
```

and put this line:

```
onooltuud.add(onoolt.getOnooltDugaar());
```

Comment: @Barns Let's hope so! :)